# Почему Symfony 2 не отрабатывает регулярное выражение в роутере/маршруте?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, symfony2

Есть регулярное выражение, которое *должно означать* "всё, исключая admin и api":

```
^(?!.*(admin|api)$).*
```

```yaml
# routing.yml
homepage:
    path: /
    host: "{slug}.site.ru"
    defaults:
        _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:homepage
    requirements:
        slug: ^(?!.*(admin|api)$).*
```

В адресной строке ввожу admin.site.ru выдаёт 100% совпадение по этому маршруту. В slug прилетает **admin** - 100%

Здесь http://www.rubular.com/ проверял регулярное выражение на правильность. Выдаёт нет совпадений (так и должно). А Symfony почему то упорно выдаёт 100% совпадение метода, как будто игнорирует регулярное выражение.

<s>В чём сила, брат?</s> **Что я делаю не так?**

Спасибо.

---

[Документация по маршрутам](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html)

Использую Symfony 2.5.12

Comment: Попробуйте `^(?!(admin|api)$).+`

Comment: @etki Попробовал. Результат тот же. Попробовал другое простое регулярное выражение \d+ оно работает. Но оно мне не подходит, потому что мне надо принимать любые входящие кроме admin и api

Comment: А если будет administrator? Тоже надо отфильтровать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "всё, исключая admin и api"
>
> ```
>  ^(?!.*(admin|api)$).*
> ```

Нет, всё заканчивающееся на ...

Чтобы исключать любые вхождения, надо убрать знак конца строки:

```
^(?!.*(admin|api)).*
```

Comment: Блин точно заработало как надо. Спасибо по-братски.